# How to avoid Leaflet path from getting selected on touch devices

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm playing around with http://leafletjs.com/ and I noticed that every layer I draw on top of my map produces a *selectable path* that gets highlighted when I touch/click on it on mobile devices (or even the built-in Chrome emulator) - which makes it not only look ugly, but visually disturbing for other functionalities on the map.

This is what I mean:

[image: GeoJSON layer gets highlighted]

You can even reproduce this on the [Quick Start example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) on the official website.

Is there any way of preventing this? Or is this Chrome specific behaviour?

**EDIT**: This has now been *fixed* in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5303. Thanks @IvanSanchez.

Comment: FYI, I created a bug report upstream at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the touch highlight with a CSS rule like this:

```
.leaflet-container {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

With the rule added, anything that's touched within the Leaflet map will received a transparent highlight.